# Postgresql Index creation for Timestamp in a given Timezone

Tags: json, postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.4, b-tree-index

I want to create an index on a column which stores a timestamp inside a JSON value in Postgres. The index needs to be converted to a timezone as well. This is the query I need to run,

```
SELECT count(*) FROM reservations 
WHERE (((json #>> ‘{details, attributes, checkIn}‘)::timestamptz
        at time zone
        (json #>> ‘{details, attributes, destinationTimeZone}’)
      )) >= ‘2020-03-17’
  AND (((json #>> ‘{details, attributes, checkIn}‘)::timestamptz
        at time zone
        (json #>> ‘{details, attributes, destinationTimeZone}’)
      )) < ‘2020-04-01’;
```

I tried creating indexes as:

1)

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY hotelUuid_checkIn_index3 ON reservations 
  (TO_TIMESTAMP(json ->> '{details,attributes,checkIn}')::timestamptz);
```

error: "*functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE*"

2)

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY hotelUuid_checkIn_index3 ON reservations 
    (TO_TIMESTAMP(json ->> '{details,attributes,checkIn}'));
```

error: "*No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.*"

3)

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY hotelUuid_checkIn_index3 ON reservations 
  (((json ->> '{details,attributes,checkIn}')::timestamptz) AT TIME ZONE 'America/SanTiego');
```

error: "*No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts*"

I am aware that this is not the correct way to create index, since it will be an overhead but at this point of time i do not want to change my data insertion logic. That's why I need to create an index.

I am using Postgresql 9.4.8 version.

Comment: What is the format of the timestamps in `json #>> ‘{details, attributes, checkIn}‘`?

Comment: Its  like this "2013-08-02T21:00:00Z"

Comment: to_timestamp and variations are not immutable as convertions rely on timezones which change in time.  You can write your own function as shown here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/250627/why-isnt-it-possible-to-cast-to-a-timestamp-in-an-index-in-postgresql

Comment: For your 3rd attempt, I get a different error, `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TIME"`